Chipmunk no collision
I probably missing something, but I could not find out.
The physics is working fine (see the video, green boxes are bodies https://youtu.be/RFkP0zuVm3U)
However, a dynamic body do not hit an static one.
Here is my relevant code that creates the body and shape.
  body_ptr body{nullptr, cpBodyFree};
  std::unordered_map<bodytype, std::function<void()>> mapping = {
      {bodytype::stationary, [&body]() {
         body = body_ptr(cpBodyNewStatic(), [](cpBody *body) { cpBodyFree(body); });
       }},
      {bodytype::kinematic, [&body]() {
         body = body_ptr(cpBodyNewKinematic(), [](cpBody *body) { cpBodyFree(body); });
       }},
      {bodytype::dynamic, [&body, &size]() {
         body = body_ptr(cpBodyNew(1.0, cpMomentForBox(1.0, size.width(), size.height())), [](cpBody *body) { cpBodyFree(body); });
       }}
  };

  const auto p = j["physics"];

  mapping[p["type"].get<bodytype>()]();

  auto shape = shape_ptr(cpPolyShapeNew(body.get(), n, vertices, cpTransformIdentity, 0.0), [](cpShape *shape) { cpShapeFree(shape); });

  cpShapeSetFriction(shape.get(), p.value("friction", 0.5f));
  cpShapeSetElasticity(shape.get(), p.value("elasticity", 0.3f));
  cpSpaceAddShape(_world->space().get(), shape.get());
  cpSpaceAddBody(_world->space().get(), body.get());

What I am missing?
I searched, but the old solutions uses a function that does not exist anymore.

After briefly looking at the documentation, it seems that you are missing the definition for the collision behavior of your shapes and the appropriate collision callbacks.
The collision type getters and setters are defined like this in the manual (link):
 cpCollisionType cpShapeGetCollisionType(const cpShape *shape) void
 cpShapeSetCollisionType(cpShape *shape, cpCollisionType value)

And then you will have to implement your collision callback functions using the Collision Handler API (link). Generally, it will involve defining the callbacks defined in this struct:
struct cpCollisionHandler {
    cpCollisionType typeA, typeB;
    cpCollisionBeginFunc beginFunc;
    cpCollisionPreSolveFunc preSolveFunc;
    cpCollisionPostSolveFunc postSolveFunc;
    cpCollisionSeparateFunc separateFunc;
    cpDataPointer userData;
};

I would also recommend you look at the example code in the manual and the open source example code to see how all of these come together, here is an example I found.
I hope this is enough to get you unstuck.

Good call, but it does not worked either. I have now one color for each collision type and the player can pass through the enemy for example, see the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/v9rv3NC

I also added an "cpSpaceAddDefaultCollisionHandler", no luck.

So is your collision between dynamic bodies working correctly?

Not yet, with the handler I can see that is colliding because of a printf, but the player does not get stopped

So I feel the next steps would be to program the collision behavior. Have you defined a collision handler to resolve collisions between dynamic and static shapes?
And how are you defining your postSolveFunc , this function should contain the logic of the collision.
Here is an example I found that checks for collisions between BULLET_TYPE and MONSTER_TYPE and removes the shape and body in the postStepRemove function.
